# Searching lexicographically sorted vector<vector <int> > in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stl

I need to sort a `vector<vector<int> > vecOfVectors;` lexicographically.

So, my vecOfVectors before sorting lexicographically is:

```
((0,100,17,2),(2,3,1,3),(9,92,81,8),(0,92,92,91),(10,83,7,2),(1,2,3,3))
```

In order to do so I am using the following function:

```
std::sort(vecOfVectors.begin(),vecOfVectors.end(),lexicographical_compare);
```

So, my vecOfVectors after sorting lexicographically is now:

```
((0,92,92,91),(0,100,17,2),(1,2,3,3),(2,3,1,3),(9,92,81,8),(10,83,7,2))
```

Now given a vector I need to search its position in this sorted vecOfVectors -- somthing like binary search will work great. Is there some build in function in c++ stl that I can use to perform the binary search?

For example:
the position of (0,92,92,91) is 0; position of (0,100,17,2) is 1; position of (1,2,3,3) is 2; position of (2,3,1,3) is 3; position of (9,92,81,8) is 4; position of (10,83,7,2) is 5.

Comment: No need of any binary search, you can just create a function compare(vector<int>,vector<int>) which tells which among them is lexicographically first.

Comment: @MadhuKumar Sounds great, can you please explains with the help of an example

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for a binary search algorithm in C++?

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to add `lexicographical_compare`, that's already how vectors are compared.

Depending on your exact use case you're looking for [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) or [`std::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/), [`std::binary_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) or [`std::equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/)- all of these operate on sorted vectors.

A complete example with your data and c++11 is below. It constructs your vector, sorts it (showing the order you mention), then finds a single value in the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void print(const std::vector<int> & v) {
    std::cout<<"(";
    for(auto x=v.begin(); x!=v.end(); ++x) {
        std::cout<<*x<<",";
    }
    std::cout<<")";
}

void print(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> & v) {
    std::cout<<"(";
    for(auto x=v.begin(); x!=v.end(); ++x) {
        print(*x);
        std::cout<<",";
    }
    std::cout<<")"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v {
        {0,100,17,2},
        {2,3,1,3},
        {9,92,81,8},
        {0,92,92,91},
        {0,92,92,91},
        {10,83,7,2},
        {1,2,3,3}
    };

    print(v);

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    print(v);

    std::vector<int> key = { 0,100, 17, 2 };

    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), key);
    if(it!=v.end() && key==*it) {
        std::cout<<"Found it"<<std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Not found"<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: ok thank you..can u please illustrate this with an example for vector<int>

Comment: You forgot `std::equal_range`.

Comment: `it` can be `.end()`, in which case you can't dereference it. You have to check `if (it != vecOfVector.end() && *i == key) ... `.

Comment: In std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); do I need to give lexicographic_compare

Comment: @JannatArora No you dont. _There's no need to add `lexicographical_compare`, thats already how vectors are compared._

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments create a function:

```
bool compare(vector<int> A,vector<int> B)
{
  int i=0;
  while(i<(A.size()<B.size())?A.size():B.size())
    {
      if(A[i]<B[i])
        {
          return 1;
        }
      else if(A[i]==B[i])
        {
         i++;
        }
      else
        {
          return 0;
        }
      }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: is 5 the size of A.size()

Comment: yeah you can replace 5 with A.size()

Comment: Downvoted: only works for fixed vectors of length 5. Vectors already have an overloaded `operator<`  that compares lexicographically

Comment: Sorry, no not really. It only works for `int`. Generalize this enough and you will have reinvented `operator<`, which is the iodiomatic and foolproof way to do vector comparisons.